How to Prevent exceljs from Adding @ to Formulas?
Stack Overflow community!
I'm using the exceljs library in Vue3 project to generate Excel files with formulas. However, I've noticed that exceljs automatically prepends an @ symbol to certain formulas, which I want to avoid. This behavior seems to be related to the implicit intersection operator introduced in Excel 2016, but it's not desired in my use case.
When I set a formula in a cell using exceljs, like this:
worksheet.getCell('A1').value = { formula: `XLOOKUP(${fatherLetter}${rowNumber}, ${fatherCatalog || ''},${valorRange},"",0,1)` }

The resulting Excel file shows the formula as =@XLOOKUP(E2, Sheet2!$I$1:$I$2,Sheet2!$J$1:$J$2,"",0,1) instead of =XLOOKUP(E2, Sheet2!$I$1:$I$2,Sheet2!$J$1:$J$2,"",0,1)
